# Better vertical alignment of Icons in React Native

Tags: react-native, icons

I'm trying to create a little floating "vote up/down" widget in the bottom of my app screen. I'm using React Native with Nativebase and [Entypo Icons](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons#bundled-icon-sets).

The problem is the icons just dont seem to be vertically aligned very well, at least not through the center as I'd expect/hope. See below:
[image]

*(dotted lines added to show the issue, I'd expect those to align with their counterparts)*
When hovering the icon itself in the element inspector it appears to be equally padded (or lack there of) on every side, so I'm not sure that it's a code issue:
[image]

Here is the code:

```
 <View style={{flexDirection:'row', borderWidth: 0.5, borderColor: '#d8d8d8', borderRadius: 50, backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, .7)',     shadowColor: "#000", shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 }, shadowOpacity: 0.1, shadowRadius: 1.5, elevation: 3,alignItems:'center', marginBottom: 10,  position: 'absolute', left: '50%', marginLeft: -87, width: 174, paddingLeft: 5, paddingRight: 5,  bottom: 0,justifyContent:'space-between'}}>
    <Icon name='triangle-down'  onPress={    this.swipeLeft} active color="white" style={{fontSize: 60, marginTop:0, paddingTop:0, paddingBottom: 0, marginBottom: 0, alignSelf:  'center', height: 60,color: '#FF003C',backgroundColor:'transparent'}} />
    <Icon name='cw' style={{fontSize: 26, lineHeight: 26, height: 26, borderRadius: 50, color: '#d8d8d8',backgroundColor:'transparent'}} />
    <Icon name='triangle-up' onPress={    this.swipeRight} active color="white" style={{fontSize: 60, marginTop:0, paddingTop:0, paddingBottom: 0, marginBottom: 0, alignSelf:  'center',color: '#00C176', height: 60, backgroundColor:'transparent'}} />
</View>
```

(complete with way too many inline styles but this is pre-cleanup so try to bear with me)

Is there any way I can get the icons to align better? Also, is there any way to shrink the padded space around the icon (highlighted blue) without shrinking the actual icon?

Comment: While working with alignment, one good way to debug is by adding a backgroundColour to the element we are working with, so we fully understand it's margins and passings. In your case, add a yellow background Color to both your triangles and see the if spaces above/below is it a padding space, a margin or maybe it icon is just a little bit small and you might want to increase its size.